# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a project named Site.Dal that compiles using netstandard2.0.

csproj is :

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.1;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Models\Models\Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This project is referenced in a .netframework 4.7.2 project.
When I run it, it fails with error: "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform".
This is a dependancy of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.

I've spent few hours on this problem, reading tons of article than all mention to add in the csproj:

```html
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\$(ProjectName).deps.json" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\$(ProjectName).deps.json" />
  </Target>
```

The .deps.json file is present in the bin\debug direction but it still fails.
It looks like the problem is because I'm calling a netstandard2.0 library from dotnetframework and I have to stay with the mix core/framework.

Comment: forgot to mention that CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies is set to true but apparently it is not copying the sqlclient dlls of the different OS.

Comment: looks like the sqlclient runtime is not copied to the output.

Comment: I was on linux and tried all solutions. In the end, I found out linux distro has a buggy `dotnet` sdk and runtime package

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and resolved it by simply installing the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package.